# Tensor product of universal highest-weight modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $\tilde{\frak g}=\frak g \otimes \mathbb C[t,t^{-1}]$ be the loop algebra associated to a finite-dimensional simple Lie algebra $\frak g$.
Consider $U,V$ and $W$ universal  finite-dimensional highest-weight  $U(\tilde{\frak g})$-modules of different highest weights and suppose that they generated by $u,v$ and $w$, respectively. Suppose these modules have unique irreducible quotient $U'$, $V'$ and $W'$ respectively such that

1) $W$ is generated by $u\otimes v$ as $U(\tilde{\frak g})$-module.

2) There exists a surjective homomorphism $W \to U\otimes V$ defined by $w\mapsto u\otimes v$.

3) $W'\cong U'\otimes V'$ as $U(\tilde{\frak g})$-modules.

For this scenery, could it be shown that $W\cong U\otimes V$ as $U(\tilde{\frak g})$-module?

**Motivation:** These modules are the well known Weyl modules and its irreducible quotients. So, it is very interesting to work with tensor products and so on.

Comment: I'm curious about condition 3: How often is a tensor product of finite dimensional irreducibles irreducible?

Comment: @Chris: Your formulation is confusing to me, for instance the use of tilde in the first line.   And what is meant here by "universal finite dimensional highest weight" modules (presumably for the loop algebra)?  What is the source of "well known Weyl modules" here? Etc.

Comment: @Scott: Certainly in characteristic 0 representation theory, it's very uncommon for a tensor product of finite dimensional irreducibles to be irreducible when both factors are nontrivial (though somewhat less so in prime characteristic). I can't immediately decipher the question. 

Comment: The modules U, V, and W are not finite dimensional....

Comment: @Andy B: What are you trying to say?

Comment: @Jim: I corrected the use of tilde, sorry. The term "$X$ is the universal finite-dimensional highest weight module of highest weight $\mu$" is used to say that if you have another finite-dimensional highest weight module of same highest weight $\mu$, then it is a quotient of $X$. These modules in question are parametrized by tuples of polynomials with constant term equal to $1$. So, condition (3) here comes from a condition of primality between theirs parameters.

Comment: @Jim: The source of "well known Weyl modules" is essentially the works of Chari (with different people). For instance, arxiv.org/abs/0704.3819, arxiv.org/abs/math/0004174, arxiv.org/abs/0906.2014.



Comment: @Chris: You made it sound like they are finite dimensional was all.

Comment: @Andy B: They are finite-dimensional as stated!